# Having a service called with STOMP which accepts more than one parameter

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, stomp

I'm giving the [Spring's STOMP+WebSocket implementation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) a try and I wonder if it's possible to call a service (at server) which takes in more than one parameter?

I get it that I can encapsulate a number of parameters into one class and then define a service taking in an object of that class. But that's not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to call one service through REST and STOMP at the same time. And since REST services are all about multiple parameter methods, I wonder how can I call them through STOMP!?

Comment: _"REST services are all about multiple parameter methods"_ Not really. And parameters are part of the URL, aren't they?

Comment: In Spring REST you've got `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` (AFAIK) and your services can take in arbitrary number of them (except for request body which is unique). But going to the STOMP+WebSocket I can not see anything of similar.

Comment: Spring STOMP support has `@DestinationVariable`. But REST and STOMP are inherently different. So they possibly share the same Endpoints or even provide the same service (i.e. functionality)?

Comment: That's perfect. But now that I have `@DestinationVariable`, should I annotate the STOPM's main message somehow? Something like `@ReqeuestBody` in REST? If you post an answer with examples on `@PathVariable`, `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody` and their equivalent in STOMP, I'll be more than glad to mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RequestParam` is for query parameters and they don't make much sense when the client sends data to the server as opposed to a query. Both REST and STOMP allow you to use headers for meta information.

The equivalent of `@PathVariable` is `@DestinationVariable` and used the same way.

The equivalent of `@RequestBody` is `@Payload`, but Spring assumes that a method parameter without an annotation is the payload, so it's not really needed.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/bar/{id}")
@ResponseBody
@MessageMapping("/foo/bar/{id}")
@SendTo("/baz")
public Answer method(
    @PathVariable @DestinationVariable int id,
    @RequestBody Message message,
    @RequestHeader("foo") @Header("foo") String foo) {
```